# flex Align-content not registering

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

This one baffles me there is not other CSS yet, I cant seem to get align-content to push my flex items into the middle of the page? any help would be appreciated I'm probably missing something very obvious.

I tried deleting flex-wrap and changing align-content to align-items with the same result the tiles are still stuck to the top.

```
body {
      font-family: 'Sono', sans-serif;
    }

.pricing-container{
      display: flex;
      flex-basis: 300px;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      justify-content: space-around;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-content: center;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```
<body>
  <div class="pricing-container">
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Basic</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$9.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>✅ 10GB Storage</li>
        <li>✅ 1 User</li>
        <li> Support</li>
      </ul>
      <span><button class="plan-button">Sign Up</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Standard</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$19.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>✅ 50GB Storage</li>
        <li>✅ 5 Users</li>
        <li>✅ Phone &amp; Email Support</li>
      </ul>
      <span><button class="plan-button">Sign Up</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Premium</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$49.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>✅ 100GB Storage</li>
        <li>✅ 10 Users</li>
        <li>✅ 24/7 Support</li>
      </ul>
      <span><button class="plan-button">Sign Up</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I figured it out, you have to set the height of the container before it will move. Thanks anyway